# Examples: Sequence of derivatives $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(x)\neq \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\right)'$

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, sequence-of-function

I am looking for some interesting examples of sequences of functions/of derivatives which satisfy the follwoing conditions:

1. $f_n'(x)$ must converge pointwisely,
2. $f_(x)$ should converge uniformly or pointwisely,
3. $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(x)\neq \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\right)'$.

---

So far I have only found:

$f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, where $f_n(x)= \frac{1}{n}x^n$ and $f_n'(x)=x^{n-1}$.

In this case:

$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\hat{0}\right)'=\hat{0} \neq \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(x)= \begin{cases} 1, \text{if } x \ne 1 \\ 0,  \text{else. } \end{cases}
$$

Maybe someone has some more examples to share :)

**EDIT**

Maybe it is possible to find an example where the limit of $f_n'(x)$ attains a "nice" form, e.g. a polynomial or an elementary function without the necessity of defining it piecewise where you have jumps.

Comment: There are examples for which the limit on the right side fails to exist (for instance, $f_n(x) = \sqrt{1/n + x^2}$). However, it is difficult to think of an example where both limits exist and equality fails to hold

Comment: In other words, the differentiation operator is typically a [closed operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem_(functional_analysis)) (or at least closable). This is due to the fact that the "inverse operator" given by integration is well-behaved.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I found this paper which has some interesting implications on my question: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-01/S0002-9939-96-02998-X/S0002-9939-96-02998-X.pdf